RIGIFY ERROR: rigging up a bunny, got several Error notices
I am trying to rig up a bunny (hare), I used the cat armature and moved the bones to fit. I got several Error notices though.
First it was RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'tail.001': Cannot connect chain - bone position is disjoint. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'. I looked in here and found someone had suggested to disconnect the parent, then re-parent it, but on “keep offset” and not “connected”.
Then I tried again and got this message: RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine': Input to rig type must be a chain of 3 or more bones. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'. It has three spine bones though so I don't know what the problem is, and I feel like I am just messing up the armature more and more. Has someone had a similar problem before and knows how to fix it?
Here's a picture of the armature, and the file link underneath!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IKedKbCtOsNq-t-OI97QfRfrV2Bs6YU2/view?usp=share_link


Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. At the moment you just have a text link to a file which may not remain available for future users to look at. Thanks.

Rigify uses specific naming conventions in its' scripts for generating the rig from the metarig and assigning the correct constraints/relationships between bones. You can't delete, dissolve or disconnect parts willy-nilly and expect it to work as normal. If you add a human/quadruped metarig go into Edit Mode > Data Properties panel > Rigify > Samples you can see that the rig is made of those components listed on this page here.

If you modified a Quadruped metarig but deleted one of the bones from the spine, or renamed one of the bones, or moved the head or tail of one of the bones the Rigify scripts won't be able to recognize it. You can add or remove parts from the metarig but they need to come from that samples panel and match the relationships specified in the docs.

To add to @Jakemoyo's comments, you also need to be very careful that some of the connections between bones are moved as one unit. Box-select over the joint between bones and move both at once to keep them connected. This is a tutorial on rigging for-legged creatures in Blender 4.0 which might help.
